# Implementation of Synchro in FPGA

Tags: fpga, synchro

Anyone implemented synchro inside FPGA. I am stuck with theta/angle conversion. I am able to convert 3phase to 2 phase using Scott-T formula.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of synchronization? It looks like you want to implement an 3-phase transformation to either alpha-beta or D-Q? Correct?

Comment: nope. actually i want find the angle using synchro. Say, rotating shaft is connected to synchro. Synchro is connected to ADC and then to FPGA. Inn FPGA, code is written to find the angle of shaft rotation.

Comment: Welcome to the site. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your situation, work and findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Cordic? You have two orthogonal values, and wish to know the angle, pretty much what the cordic algorithm was made for.

Comment: @DanMills, any document or reference to know about Cordic and how to implement